# the formulaire html and php/pdo

Tags: html, pdo

can someone help me please I search from a week and the page post Notice: Undefined index: username in 
C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\test.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\test.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\test.php on line 21

and i don't find the problem in the code and please explaine i want to learn thank you

```
'<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input placeholder="username" type="text" name="username" ></input>
<input placeholder="password"type="password" name="password" ></input>
<input placeholder="email"type="email" name="email" ></input>
<input type="submit" value="OK"/></input>
</form>
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=guyideas;host=localhost';

$user = 'root';

$password = '';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$username = $_GET['username'];

$password = $_GET['password'];

$email = $_GET['email'];

$stmt = $dbh->exec('INSERT INTO `guyideas`.`users` (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ("'.$username.'", "'.$password.'","email");');

?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the index exist in the array before:

```
if( isset($_POST["email"]) ) { 
     ... do things with $_POST["email"] ... 
}
```

Comment: no it's don't work because i try this                                                                                                                   'if( isset($_POST["email"]) ) {
 $email = $_GET['email'];
 echo"yes";
}'

Comment: @GuySharony - Take a look at the form's **method attribute** value - It's set to `post` - change it to `get` and then you could refer to the data by using `$_GET["email"]`

Comment: sorry but it's don't work i try this code----------------------------------------------if(isset($_GET["email"]) ) {
 $email = $_GET["email"];
}else{
 echo"non";
}

Comment: @GuySharony Have you changed to form opening tag to `<form action="test.php" method="get">`? (Notice that here it's **get** and NOT **post**)

Comment: ho! Thank you i will tack car the next time!